# Hibernate remove on child does not work if there are other childs

Tags: java, hibernate

there is a entity 'address' and another entity 'building'.
At a address there can be multiple buildings.

On building.java I do have address defined with:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "ADDRESS_ID_REF")
public Address getAddress() {
    return this.address;
}
```

On address building is defined as:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "address")
public Set<Building> getBuildings() {
    return this.buildings;
}
```

When trying to do
`em.remove(building)`
it does work

- fine when there is only on building at one address
- bad when there are two buildings on the same address

The bad case is constructed exactly like the good case plus inserting a second building into database with reference to the same address.

- insert into address values ('address123', [...]);
- insert into building values ('building234', 'address123', [...]);
- insert into building values ('building235', 'address123', [...]);

In bad case (hibernate isnt doing any remove) I am still able to delete the row within database (`delete from building where building_id = '123'`).No SQL errors regarding references.

In similar threads I read that in this case usually there are left references such that hibernate correctly cannot remove this entity.

Unfortunately I am also not getting any log4j output of hibernate and no exceptions occur. So I do not know what the problem of hibernate is at this place.

My log4j.properties works fine for my loggers. Outputs are written as expected to console.
But I do not get any Hibernate logging.
I read in another thread that this logger should give me some hints:
org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener

```
log4j.rootLogger=TRACE, A1
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n

log4j.category.com.myproject.mypackage=INFO
log4j.category.com.myproject.mypackage.myclass=DEBUG

log4j.category.org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener=TRACE
log4j.category.org.hibernate=TRACE
log4j.category.org.springframework=TRACE
```

When setting in persistence.xml show_sql to true, I will get the SQLs written to console. There I can see that no delete sql is executed. But I do not see any errors.

```
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
<property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
```

As written in most cases in other threads there seem to be some references left which had to be deleted first.
But in my case, my entity is child object which means I do not expect the foreign on building directing to address to be a problem.
Additionally I am able to delete the building-row directly via SqlDeveloper.
And when changing my code from

```
em.remove(building)
```

to

```
em.remove(address)
```

All three entities are deleted due to cascading. But this isnt what I want, I only want to get the single building being deleted.
I think to get it, I need to see the missing hibernate loggings (hopefully there are some).

If you need further information please ask for them.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This would be a comment, but I have not enough reputation) What are you trying to achieve or better what doesn't work? deleting building should not delete the address as there is no cascade option in your @ManyToOne annotation. if you are trying to delete building on removing it from buildings set, you need to use orphanRemoval = true in @OneToMany annotation

EDIT (after reading the comment)

The simplest way would be following:
add orphanRemoval=true to @OneToMany address mapping. Than

```
Building b .... // current Object to be deleted
b.getAddress().getBuildings().remove(b);
b.setAddress(null);
em.merge(a);
```

for this piece of code

```
b.getAddress().getBuildings().remove(b);
b.setAddress(null);
```

you can create separate method in address entity like

```
public void removeBuilding(Building b){
    buildings.remove(b);
    b.setAddress(null);
}
```

Comment: yes, I only want the single child to be deleted wthout deleting enything else. i still tried, it does not affect anything

Comment: since orphanRemoval was introduced in JPA1, how was the way to do it before? Adding a property "orphanRemoval=true" sounds like a non-standard feature since its not enabled by default in hibernate. What would  be the way without using orphanRemoval?

Comment: is it neccessary to do 'b.setAddress(null);'? probably not. But orphan removal seems to be "the way" to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this is correct and intended by the framework but I found a solution/workaround:

Instead of only doing:

```
em.remove(b);
```

I am now doing:

```
Building b .... // current Object to be deleted
Address a = b.getAddress();
Set<Building> bSet = a.getBuildings();
bSet.remove(b);
em.remove(b);
```

This works fine. Hopefully this is valid doing.

The explanation could be: removing an child-entity does not update the parents list of children even when the transactional method is ended (means a commit is done).

I had expected that when deleting an child-entity and doing commit, this entity is deleted from database.

When then in a new transaction loading a parent entity, all its child entities are retrieved from database, hence the removed child-entity is not listed any more at parent side.

Maybe (although of transactional executions) some data is kept in cache?

As said in the other comment only adding orphanRemoval=true to the cascadeAll-Line in Address-entity does not effect anything.

Comment: probably I missunderstood orphan removal because it exists only since JPA2. When enabling orphanRemoval and just removing my Child from the parents set of childs and then commiting, the child will be deleted by orphanRemoval without doing explicit entityManager.remove(child). I think I am doing "the old way by hand" (no orphanRemoval, remove child from parents set of childs, remove child by entityManager) and the new way is using orphanRemoval (orphanRemoval=true, delete child from parents set of Childs).